# List top queries by total runtime, execution time, wait/queue time in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I know Amazon has provided various admin scripts for Redshift, such as this one:

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminScripts/top_queries.sql

which lists the top queries by runtime, and I also found this which is similar:

https://chartio.com/learn/amazon-redshift/identifying-slow-queries-in-redshift/

however I'd like to know if there is a query which is similar to the above queries but also shows queue/wait time in addition to execution time?

From this post:

[How can I get the total run time of a query in redshift, with a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473901/how-can-i-get-the-total-run-time-of-a-query-in-redshift-with-a-query)

I gather that the stl_query table includes the execution time + wait time, but that the stl_wlm_query includes the total_exec_time, which is just the execution time.

**Update:** I've got the following which gives me what I want, but it seems to only return the last month or so of data, any ideas how I get older data?

```
    SELECT
w.userid,
w.query,
w.service_class_start_time AS "Day",
w.total_queue_time / 60000000 AS "Total Queue Time Minutes",
w.total_exec_time / 60000000 AS "Total Exec Time Minutes",
w.total_queue_time / 60000000 + w.total_exec_time / 60000000 AS "Total Time  Minutes"
FROM
stl_wlm_query w
ORDER BY
6 DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will list top queries by execution time, but as John mentions above, will only return two to five days of log history.

```
SELECT
w.userid,
w.query,
w.service_class_start_time AS "Day",
w.total_queue_time / 60000000 AS "Total Queue Time Minutes",
w.total_exec_time / 60000000 AS "Total Exec Time Minutes",
w.total_queue_time / 60000000 + w.total_exec_time / 60000000 AS "Total Time  Minutes"
FROM
stl_wlm_query w
ORDER BY
6 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

That query is using the `stl_wlm_query` table.

From [STL Tables for Logging - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_intro_STL_tables.html):

> To manage disk space, the STL log tables only retain approximately **two to five days of log history**, depending on log usage and available disk space. If you want to retain the log data, you will need to periodically copy it to other tables or unload it to Amazon S3.

Comment: Thanks John! I can't upvote yet, but this was helpful.